# How to Send a Message to a Facebook Group With a Shared User

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

There are many duplicates to doing this, but I want to be able to share a post  without the user logging in as his Facebook user but rather have him use the website's dedicated Facebook user, which will manage the groups we will be sharing to.

Also, if possible, to have the login process of the dedicated user automated in the background - so the user will simply choose what to share and that's it.

I'm currently using C# facebook sdk but I can't figure out exactly how to do it.

Code sample that requires the client to already be logged in, works for my user, not a dedicated one:

```
if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                    app_id, redirectUri, scope));
            }
            else
            {
                List<PublishedJobSupplier> lst = new List<PublishedJobSupplier>();
                using (CardsManagementServiceClient CMS = CardsManagementServiceClient.GetService(TransactionCode))
                {
                    lst = CMS.SuppliersListGetByPublishedJob(TransactionCode, JobId);
                }
                string groupName = lst[lst.Count - 1].SupplierName;

                Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
             app_id, redirectUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...  Separates tokens.
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                            token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                    }
                }

                string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

                var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
                dynamic somat = client.Get("/me/groups");
                //somat.data is array
                for (int i = 0; i < somat.data.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (somat.data[i].name == groupName)
                    {
                        client.Post("/" + somat.data[i].id + "/feed", new { message = string.Format("I am posting from the HRMS to JobId: {0} to " + groupName, hiddenJobId.Value) });
                    }
                }
   }
```

I'd appreciate any guidelines/tips on this matter, if it is possible.

Comment: What is a "website's dedicated Facebook user"? You are only allowed to have one Facebook account and it needs to have your name. And it is not possible to login in the background even if you have username and password

Comment: @WizKid I mean by that that when you will press the share button in the website, it will be post using the website's own unique facebook username, not a client's one.